# Flashing ROM on a used Samsung Note 4

Tags: malware, system, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I have a used note 4 and want to make sure there is no spyware or malware on it. I know some can survive a factory reset. Somebody told me to flash a rom and recovery image but not how to do this. I searched and came across a video of a person using a program called odin to do this, however after he was finished all his apps were still there. If this completely cleans the phone why are his apps still there?

What would be the best way for me to actually wipe everything on the phone?

Comment: I've no experience with Samsung devices, but generally, if you flash a ROM, affected partitions are completely overwritten (one can make sure of that by wiping them beforehand). Apps that "remained" are most likely part of the ROM, so they didn't remain but were reinstalled. For data to be gone, a factory reset should be made.

Comment: I don't think they were reinstalled. I think this program odin doesn't delete everything. I have seen videos of people instantly having their files back with no reinstall or backup necessary. I'm just curious if there is some other setting or other program that could do this. I was expecting this to have a quick and easy answer.

Comment: Maybe someone with Windows & Odin experience can give that, I have neither. I usually use [tag:twrp] recovery for that job (including wiping the resp. partitions) – but I'm not sure if that can be done on your device. At least there's no official TWRP for it.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's better to link the video so we know what you are exactly talking about.
2. My guess is you watched a video about rooting using ODIN. Yes, that won't wipe your device clean. However you can also use ODIN to flash entire firmware which cleans up everything on your device.

[Here's a guide to use ODIN to flash stock firmware](https://forums.androidcentral.com/ambassador-guides-tips-how-tos/499009-guide-samsung-how-flash-stock-rom-via-odin-new-interface.html).

Comment: The video is https://youtu.be/1TsTQeSXJBA it uses the same settings as the link you posted. All the apps remained and it seemed like all his settings were still there.

Comment: @Jamesredo You can always factory reset (wipe `/data`) manually by booting into recovery with `POWER`+`HOME`+`VOL_UP` then choosing the corresponding option. Flashing factory firmware is just to guarantee you that no suspicious element is left in `/system`.

Comment: Did you watch the video? Seems like stuff remains. Is there another way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I didn't (before you mentioned it). Now that I skimmed through it, I found nothing that contradicts my statement - the guy in the video didn't manually do a factory reset, hence everything the user created (`/data`) is still there. If you aren't satisfied with what's left on the phone *after* a factory reset... Those are embedded within the OS by either Samsung or the carrier that issued the update, and they are supposed to be trusted (spy/malware-wise).